# jQuery / Smarty Get request data to php function and back

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, smarty

does anyone know if possible or how to submit a form, use get to get a posted varable, pass it via ajax to a php function then return the data?

we currently have it on a normal form submit and using smarty to return the data but ive come across the problem with placing this inside a tab so though best to do ajax based to prevent reloading of the page - current working code is as follows:

```
    {assign var="postocde" value=$smarty.request.postcode}
{assign var="postcode_var" value=$postocde|fn_get_found_locations} 
{assign var="postcode_final" value=$postcode_var}

<div id="postcode_result" {if $postcode_final == '1' || $postcode_final == '2'}class="postcode_result"{/if}>

    {if $postcode_final == '1'}

        {$lang.restricted_shipping_fail}

    {elseif $postcode_final == '2'}

        {$lang.restricted_shipping_success}

    {/if}

</div>

<form method="get" action="{$seo_url.href}" name="restricted_locator" id="restricted_locator" class="cm-ajax">

    <div class="form-field">

    <label for="postcode">{$lang.restricted_shipping_label}:</label>

    <input type="text" value="" name="postcode" size="50" class="input-text cm-hint" id="postcode" />

    </div>

    <input id="submit_postcode" type="submit" value="search" class="moreButton" />

</form>
```

really appriciate is someone could help or shed some light on this

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the jQuery AJAX call.  It will return what ever is echoed out from the php page processing the request.  So if you need multiple variables back you can have it echo a JSON string.

### Script on page:

```
<script>
$("#restricted_locator").submit(function(sub){

    sub.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',  
        url:    '{$seo_url.href}',  
        data:   $('#restricted_locator').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(returned){

        // Anything echoed in process-sendform.php will be stored as var "returned"

        }
    });
});

console.log(returned); // will yield the string: "This string will be sent back to page."

</script>
```

### PHP script to send to:

If you already have a function defined you can just post it in like this.  It may be easier to just reformat the function into it's own page rather than incorporating it into a page.

```
<?php

$value1 = $_POST['value1ToFeedToFunction'];
$value2 = $_POST['value1ToFeedToFunction'];
$value3 = $_POST['value1ToFeedToFunction'];
$value4 = $_POST['value1ToFeedToFunction'];

function performFunction($val1,$val2,$val3,$val4){

    // do what ever you need to do with passed values here  
    echo "This string will be sent back to page.";


}

performFunction($value1,$value2,$value3,$value4);

?>
```

## EDIT: Regarding your undefined function error

You must include jQuery in the head of your document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
```

Comment: helped loads thanks, but instead of the url being a php file can it be a php function t hat i can call? as you see in smarty we use {assign var="postcode_var" value=$postocde|fn_get_found_locations} working like fn_get_found_locations($postcode)

Comment: The easiest way that this could be done is if the function is contained within the php file that you are sending to via AJAX.  Just post that function into the php file and pass the values to that function.  Code to follow... Give me a sec.

Comment: will give it a try thanks very much, the function is in its own php file with other functions and the form in a tpl file - will this still work out? im going to give it a try now though :) thanks!

Comment: It would be better to just separate any of the processing that you need to be done into a completely separate PHP file.  You don't want to have to process/load any extra content for a simple form call.  If there is a bunch of extra code that isn't going to be used by the submission of the form, it will slow down the call.

Comment: ok cool, will place into a new php file and let you know how it goes! thanks ever so much for the solution

Comment: No problem! If it helped you out, would you mind marking it as the answer?

Comment: `$("#restricted_locator").submit(function(sub){

    sub.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',  
        url:    'addons/restricted_locator/controllers/customer/lookup.php',  
        data:   $('#restricted_locator').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(returned){

        // Anything echoed in process-sendform.php will be stored as var "returned"

        }
    });
});

console.log(returned); // will yield the string: "This string will be sent back to page."`

Comment: Do you have the jQuery package referenced in your file head? you will need that package called before you can use the ajax function.